# Assort elements in ndarray in python

Tags: python, list

I want to assort the elements in an array, let's say

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(19680801)
a=np.random.randint(3,size=49).reshape(7,7)
```

but right now, I want to put them in different groups based on the value of the third or fouth dimensions. For example, for the row elements in a. If element[3]=0 and element[4]=0, then put it in the group 1; If the element[3]=0 and element[4]=1, then put it in the group 2 and so on......

How can I do it?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my system, your code yields

```
a = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2],
             [2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0],
             [1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2],
             [1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0],
             [1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0],
             [2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2],
             [0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0]])
```

You can acces `a` using a condition like this:

```
a[a[:,3]==0]
Out[14]: 
array([[2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0],
       [1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0]])
```

and you can use boolean operators to chain conditions to your liking. In your case you want, for example, all rows that have `0` at index `3` and `4` (note: no rows match that criteria):

```
a[(a[:,3]==0) & (a[:,4]==0)]
Out[16]: array([], shape=(0, 7), dtype=int64)
```

Which you can then use to construct your groups:

```
g1 = a[(a[:,3]==0) & (a[:,4]==0)]
# Same logic for any other groups you want
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
g1, g2, g3 = [], [], [] # init groups 1, 2, 3 as empty lists
for e in a:
    if e[3] == 0 and e[4] == 0:
        g1.append(e)
    elif e[3] == 0 and e[4] == 1:
        g2.append(e)
    else:
        g3.append(e)
```

Result:

```
>print(g1)
[]

>print(g2)
[array([1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2])]

>print(g3)
[array([0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2]),
 array([2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0]),
 array([1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0]),
 array([1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0]),
 array([2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2]),
 array([0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0])]
```